# Solarized theme in both mc and Terminator

Tags: terminal, colors, mc, gnome-terminator

I have [configured Terminator to use Solarized color theme](https://github.com/ghuntley/terminator-solarized).

[I did the same for MC](https://github.com/peel/mc/).

However, the problem I have is that I don't get actual Solarized color scheme in MC (as there already is one below and the skin expects default white-on-black Terminator color profile).

How can I fix this? I was thinking about configuring Terminator to change them whenever MC is launched but I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I am using MC 4.8 and the following works for that version:

1. create a `~/.config/mc/skins` directory
2. copy (or link) the `.ini` file defining the skin into `~/.config/mc/skins`
3. edit `.config/mc/ini` adding a line containing `skin=solarized` to the section `Midnight-Commander`.